# AngularJS: A page calls my angularjs-page with form POST data

Tags: angularjs

How would it be to call an AngularJS page from a totally different, that is not mine, and the caller page uses POST with form-data. Is there needed for some special web server setup on my side, or can Angular handle this incoming POST request totally without any help from server side logic on my side (so my Angular-page can be served from anywhere, like a simple file server like Dropbox)?

Comment: USE var responsePromise = $http.post("PAGE URL HERE", dataObject, {});

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. Another and different page calls my Angular-page. It could call my Angular-page like this, using GET: http://myangularpage.com?id=3, then all would be ok. But in this case the "other page" cannot call the Angular-page with like this, it uses POST with the id included that way. I will try to clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean angular page to angular page communication?

Angular runs in your browser, so what you want is client to client communication. You would have to build it around your server by yourself. The easiest way would be to use WebSockets.

client sends message to server -> server sends message to target client -> client receives the message

or

client sends message to server -> server stores the message and waits for client to pick it up -> client picks the message from server

If you mean page X calls your angular page via a POST request.

Your angular page communicates with the server all the time. So you should not try to catch the post request to your page inside angular (you can't anyways), you have to catch it on the server and the somehow load the appropriate page where your angular logic kicks in.

**You cant catch post requests in your browser, only on your server.**

[image]

Comment: I do not need client-client communication that way. I am stuck with a web page (not mine) that calls my angular using POST and some form data (like the id in my GET example). My question is: Can my Angular page handle this incoming POST request totally without any help from a web server (my web server)?

Comment: @EricC No you cant, post request goes to your server, not your browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you put this as an answer, ok could accept it :) Just change this question...